# manipulating alpha channel on a mov file

Tags: c#, api, quicktime

i am working on a project given to me and i have a problem,

what i need is to write a program that can embed subtitles into a mov(quickTime) file

i was hoping to get some directions here since i am clueless on how to do so.

after a lot of googling i found something called qtkit but it only works with objective c

can i do something like this in c#?

or even is there another movie format that supports high def subtitles in alpha channel

thanks a lot in advance
jony

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can imbed subtitles in a quicktime .mov file using QuickTime in a C# application. In Visual Studio I recommend you target .NET 3.5 at least initially (You can target 4.0 but see my other post about this on Stack Overflow). In Visual Studio C# project right click on the Toolbox and select Choose Items... option. Select COM tab in displayed dialog box and then select Apple Quicktime Control 2.0. This will but the Apple QT Control 2.0 in the Toolbox for you to use. Drag the Quicktime Control 2.0 to your WinForm and now you can easily load a .mov file or practically any other valid media file into this QT Control. From here you could "embed subtitles" into the .mov file in a number of ways. You could overlay text, use subtitling, SMIL, or GDI+ to write text on to each frame needing text. You can find out how to use each of these methods by referencing John Cromie's book "Quicktime for .NET and COM Developers". I believe there are some chapters of this book online, but if your serious about this project you should pick up a copy of the book - (Amazon and others).